# Do the albums mentioned below cover all soundtracks of the series Naruto and Naruto Shippuuden?

Tags: naruto, theme-song

**Naruto:**

- Naruto Original Soundtrack I
- Naruto Original Soundtrack II
- Naruto Original Soundtrack III

---

**Naruto Shippuuden:**

- Naruto Shippuden Original Soundtrack I
- Naruto Shippuden Original Soundtrack II
- Naruto Shippuden Original Soundtrack III

---

*(I didn't mention the soundtracks from the movies or games as well as the main themes from the movies or the openings and endings from the series)*

These were all albums I've been able to find. But unfortunately, I couldn't find Tenten's theme (it wasn't covered in an album but only as an individual track) which made me wonder if I did find all the tracks from the franchise.

On [amazon.co.uk](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00NKQSX6O/ref=dm_ws_sp_ps_dp) I've been able to find Tenten's theme as well as other themes which aren't covered in the albums above.
But since that album is titled "*The Greatest Instrumental Themes from Naruto*" I doubt that I was able to see every track of Naruto.

Answer (score 1):

No. As an avid fan of the OST of Naruto and Naruto Shippuden, I can say that the soundtracks you mentioned don't cover all the BGM's in the anime. They only include tracks that are played regularly in stereotyped sequences. Like 'Will of Fire' is only played during flashback/sad sequences and 'Morning' is played all across filler episodes.

Having said that, there are indeed few BGM's which are not a part of the 3 collections you mentioned. Like the BGM from Naruto episodes 210-212 where Naruto and Todoroki are chasing to find Todoroki's brother and the Shinobazu hideout. The soundtrack played during those episodes is rarely repeated. So, it didn't make the cut into those volumes.

Comment: Is it possible to find these soundtracks which weren't implemented in the volumes somewhere? I don't know if it's true, but I've heard of cases in which these sort of soundtracks have been released as unofficial ones a bit after the release of the official volumes.